# Get pid of function executed in background

Tags: bash, unix, process

Is it possible to get PID of function executed in background from the function itself?

```
#!/bin/bash

Foo()
{
  echo PId=$$ #I want pid of process that executed the function!
}

echo Main PID=$$


Foo &  #execute function in background
echo SUBPID=$! #get the pid of last executed background process, in this case Foo

wait
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
Foo()
{
   echo $PPID # pid of process that executed the function
}
```