# Get PID from within backgrounded function in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, ksh

This looks like a duplicate of [Get pid of function executed in background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36911697/get-pid-of-function-executed-in-background) but it isn't. The accepted answer in that was the scripts parent process id.

The following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

function foo {
  # I want to know my PID
  echo foo PID=$$
  echo foo PPID=$PPID
  sleep 1
}

echo Script PID=$$
echo Script PPID=$PPID
foo &
echo job PID=$!
ps -fH
wait
```

Produces the following output:

```
Script PID=3694
Script PPID=27899
job PID=3695
foo PID=3694
foo PPID=27899
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
fred     27899  6622  0 11:03 pts/10   00:00:00 /bin/bash
fred      3694 27899  0 15:10 pts/10   00:00:00   /bin/bash /tmp/test
fred      3695  3694  0 15:10 pts/10   00:00:00     /bin/bash /tmp/test
fred      3697  3695  0 15:10 pts/10   00:00:00       sleep 1
fred      3696  3694 99 15:10 pts/10   00:00:00     ps -fH
```

Since foo() is run in the background I expected $$, within foo, to evaluate to its PID (3695) but it doesn't it evaluates to the calling scripts PID (3694).

Within the function foo, how do I get its own PID?

UPDATE: Changed `ps -fp $!` to `ps -fH` as requested

Comment: Please, instead of  `ps -fp $!` use `ps -fH -p $$` so you can see the whole process tree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a simple way to do it that works for both bash and ksh (and possibly other shells).

```
$SHELL -c 'echo $PPID'
```

When the above command is invoked PPID is set to the calling process which happens to be the function foo.

Answer (score 2):

When backgrounding a function, Bash likely uses a subshell.  The `PID` and `PPID` variables are not changed, but if you echo the `BASHPID` variable, you will see it change inside your function.

I think the behavior you see is intended, but functions simply act differently compared to eternal programs launched by the shell.

You can force a separate process to be launched by putting the code from your function in a separate script and call it with

```
bash `other_script`
```

That should create a new process no matter what shell you use.

You will need to `export` any variable needed in the child, and will not be able to make assignments to variables in the child that would be visible to the parent.

Comment: Thanks. That sorts it out for bash now all I need is a solution for ksh

Comment: @Paranoid: which version of ksh do you have?

Comment: ksh reports Version AJM 93u+ 2012-08-01 (its the AST version)